# How to load SIFT features in SVM on python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I am writing following code to train in SVM on python.
I am taking 2 images as training and testing against another image.

**Code is as below :-**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

img = cv2.imread("1.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, (600,400))
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
(kps1, descs1) = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
hist1 = np.hstack(descs1)

img = cv2.imread("11.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, (600,400))
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
(kps11, descs11) = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
hist11 = np.hstack(descs11)

s = np.array(hist1)
d = np.array(hist11)

X = np.array((s,d))
y = np.array([1,2])

img = cv2.imread("2.png")
gray = cv2.resize(img, (600,400))
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
(kps2, descs2) = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
hist2 = np.hstack(descs2) 
v = np.array(hist2)

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X, y) 
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)
print(clf.predict(v))
```

I'm using descs of SIFT as input in SVM
It gives following error :-

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(clf.predict(v))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 568, in predict
    y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 305, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 474, in _validate_for_predict
    (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 26112 should be equal to 35456, the number of features at training time
```

Comment: Print the shape of `X` and `v`. The first second dimension should be same (Number of features). Are you sure that `sift.detectAndCompute` always compute the same number of descriptors for each image. If not, then you may need to correct that first

Comment: I'm pretty sure that either `X` or `v` (or both) are transposed. In scikit-learn rows (`shape[0]`) represent training samples while columns (`shape[1]`) features. The number of features must be constant and it is what the error is complaining about. Additionally, according to your `y` you only have 2 training examples, I don't know what you expect to achieve with that :S Try `X = np.row_stack([s, d])`